# Java, Database - Why have assign a new object when we can put it straight into database

Tags: java, database, oop

I have a window to let user book an appointment with some fields `(date, start time, end time, ...)` and save it into a database. Why do I need to save these fields in an object such as

```
Appointment a = new Appointment(date,start,end,...);
```

and then using `get` methods to get this set of data back instead of saving it directly into a database?

Someone tells me because of how object oriented programming works but the task is just inserting a new set of data to a database, no amendment needed.

Comment: Please show more of the relevant code. Does the database API have the ability accept an `Appointment` object? Does the `Appointment` object manipulate any of the values you give it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can put them directly, but it's inconvenient.

We work in OOP style trying not to interact with raw input data. After receiving some data, we normally construct an instance of some class and then work only with this object and its state.

It's convenient because an instance keeps all needed information about an object that it presents. We unproblematically can pass it into different methods by using only one argument (not thinking about a number of fields that we want to save).

During processing, an instance may go through few milestones (like filtering, validation) before it is prepared to persist. Therefore, it's important that such infrastructure methods take a complete, already formed object and just touch up its state.

And finally, with all of that, OOP makes your code more readable and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to do this. You can use the basic `EntityManager`, for instance, to insert values directly into any database using an `executeQuery` method. The creation of objects is mostly for -indeed- object oriented programming and I (and other OO addicts like me) prefer saving to objects first. One reason being the fact that when you want to retrieve info from the database, it's much more understandable what data actually returned. A second being a better overview of you overall code. Makes it more readable and whatnot.

Example of the EntityManager:

```
EntityManager em;
//Initialize em by setting up the database source, there's a lot of information on google =)
em.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName")
    .setParameter("custName", name)
    .setMaxResults(10)
    .getResultList();
```